# Rails: Runtime configuration of ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to send a small amount of email from my app through Gmail. Now, the SMTP settings will be determined at runtime (ie: from the db), can this be done?

--- edit ---

I can set the ActionMailer subclass (named Notifier) smtp settings in one of the class' methods. This way I can set the username and password for sending the email dynamically. The only thing is that you have to set ALL the smtp_settings. Is it possible to set just the username & password settings in the class method?

This is the code I'm using right now, it is sending:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def call(user)
    Notifier.smtp_settings = { 
      :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => "587",
      :domain => "mydomain.com",
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name => "fabian@mydomain.com",
      :password => "password"
    }

    recipients user.email
    subject    "Test test"
    body       "Test"
  end
end
```

I would like to just set the username and pw here.

Answer (score 2):

(Rails 3)

Since I call mailer like this:

```
CustomerMailer.customer_auto_inform(@form).deliver
```

In CustomerMailer class I have private method:

```
def init_email_account(shop_mail)
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => shop_mail.address,
    :port                 => shop_mail.port,
    :domain               => shop_mail.domain,
    :user_name            => shop_mail.user_name,
    :password             => shop_mail.password,
    :authentication       => shop_mail.authentication.name,
    :enable_starttls_auto => shop_mail.enable_starttls_auto
  }
end
```

Before calling **mail()** which sends email you need to call private method **init_email_account** to populate smtp_settings from database. **shop_mail** is model which stores the data about mail account settings.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since the configuration files are all Ruby, then the settings can easily be fetched from a configuration file or the like at runtime.

Here's a post I wrote a while back on [getting ActionMailer working with GMail SMTP](http://douglasfshearer.com/blog/gmail-smtp-with-ruby-on-rails-and-actionmailer).

NOTE: If you're using rails 2.3 and Ruby 1.87, you don't need the plugin and can simply use the settings in [this comment](http://douglasfshearer.com/blog/gmail-smtp-with-ruby-on-rails-and-actionmailer#comment_23614)

Comment: Yip i've seen that :)

I should've explained further, I need to be able to dynamically set the accountname & pw at runtime (ie: from the db)... I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've configured the smtp_settings in your environment or initializers, you can just set the username like so:

```
Notifier.smpt_settings.merge!({:user_name => "x", :password=> "y"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   ...

private

  def set_mailer_settings

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings.merge!({
      username: 'username',
      password: 'yoursupersecretpassword'
    })

  end

end
```

Comment: This would work, but it's not thread-safe so beware.